# How to read an ".owl" from azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks, ontology, knowledge-graph

I have to transfer my project to databricks. My project requires me to read ontology files of **".owl"** extension. I am using owlready2 package for reading .owl files.

But I am unable to read the owl file from **blob storage**.

I have tried

- using `request.get("azure file url")` but this to throws error saying - "The specified resource does not exist".
- owlready2.get_ontology("azure file url") but this fails with error saying - "HTTP Error 404: The specified resource does not exist.

PS : I am taking the "azure file url" from below :
[image: url from here]

**Looking to find away to read owl files from blob storage.**

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error is because the blob you are trying to read is in a "private" blob container (i.e. public read access is not allowed).

Create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) for the blob you're trying to read with at least "Read" permission and use the SAS URL in your code. To create a SAS, click on "Generate SAS" button shown in your screenshot.

To learn more about container ACL, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-container-acl.

To learn more about Shared Access Signature, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature.